# Dividing a 2D array by a constant in a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that will divide a 2D array by 2. I've made it like this but it only divides first row.

```
//Header file
#ifndef divider
#define divider


void arrayDivider(float* a, int i, int j);

#endif
```

```
//declaration
#include <stdio.h>
#include "divider.h"

void arrayDivider(float* a, int i, int j){
    int x,y;
    
    for(x=0; x<i*j; x++){
        a[x] = a[x] /2;
    }
}
```

```
//main code
#include <stdio.h>
#include "divider.h"
int main(){
    float array[100][100];
    int i, j;
    int x=0, y=0;
    
    printf("Please enter rows of matrix => ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Please enter columns of matrix => ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    

    
    printf("Please enter elements of your matrix:\n");
    for(x=0; x<i; x++){
        for(y=0; y<j; y++){
            scanf("%f", &array[x][y]);
        }
    }
    
    arrayDivider(&array, i, j);

    printf("   Your matrix\n------------------\n");
    
    for(x=0; x<i; x++){
        for(y=0; y<j; y++){
            printf("%f  ", array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting this to divide every value by 2 but it only divides first row. I couldn't find where the problem is. What is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 0):

With `arrayDivider(&array, i, j);` you are passing a pointer to the 2D array (i.e. a `float ***`), not the 2D array itself. Correct the call to

```
arrayDivider(array, i, j);
```

And the declaration to

```
void arrayDivider(float **a, int i, int j);
```

And just to let you know, it would be more logical to use x an y where you used i and j and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "height" of `array` variable in `main()` is not `y` but 100.

This means that `array[x][y]` actually point to `array + 100 * x + y`, not `array + x * j + y`.
The elegant solution to your problem is using Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) introduced in C99.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayDivider(int i, int j, float a[i][j]){
    int x,y;
    
    for(x=0; x<i; x++){
       for(y = 0; y < j; ++y) {
         a[x][y] = a[x][y] /2;
       }
    }
}

int main(){
    int i, j;
    int x=0, y=0;
    
    printf("Please enter rows of matrix => ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Please enter columns of matrix => ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    
    float array[i][j];

    
    printf("Please enter elements of your matrix:\n");
    for(x=0; x<i; x++){
        for(y=0; y<j; y++){
            scanf("%f", &array[x][y]);
        }
    }
    
    arrayDivider(i, j, array);

    printf("   Your matrix\n------------------\n");
    
    for(x=0; x<i; x++){
        for(y=0; y<j; y++){
            printf("%f  ", array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

for input:

```
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

it produces:

```
   Your matrix
------------------
0.500000  1.000000  1.500000  
2.000000  2.500000  3.000000
```